# ¿Cómo importo fuentes locales en Next 13.4.7?

Tags: nextjs, fuentes, next, font-faces

tengo este archivo

```
export const Brush = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: "../public/fonts/brush.woff2",
      weight: "normal",
      style: "normal",
    },
  ],
  display: "swap",
  variable: "--f-brush",
  preload: true,
});
```

en lib > fonts.ts

y lo estoy llamando asi

```
import "./globals.css";
import { Brush } from "@/lib/fonts";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={Brush.variable}>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

desde app > layout.tsx

y luego asi

```
font-family: var(--f-brush);
```

en el css donde lo quiero implementar, pero no logro que funcione. Mi idea era crear una variable global que se llame "--f-brush".

Gracias de antemano.